# Can't check whether language is available. TextToSpeech android

Tags: android

I want to make a list with only available languages, but when i call isLanguageAvailable() i get in logcat that there was some failed and this method is not bound to tts engine. I don't know what i can do in this case. This code is in MainActivity. Maybe someone have that situation or know solution?